# SPARK Reading of SEQUENCE File

Tags: apache-spark

From the various threads, blogs and indeed some of the well known books, I can see that SPARK can read a "Hive" Sequence File. But the other use case of a Sequence File genned by MR that is a container for many small files, can it read that type of file? I suspect so, but nothing seen ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, a non-sensical question looking back. There is no difference as to whether Hive table externally over this type of file, or file generated by MR. matter of progressing and to much reading and not seeing the forest for the trees. It can happen.

For posterity:

```
val RDD = sc.parallelize(List(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)))
RDD.saveAsSequenceFile("/XYZ/seq-dir")
```

Painful:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
val sequence_data = sc.sequenceFile("/XYZ/seq-dir/*", classOf[Text], classOf[IntWritable])
            .map{case (x, y) => (x.toString, y.get())}
            .collect
```